# OSI Layer 2 encryption

Tags: networking, encryption, ethernet, ipsec

I'm currently for a side project trying to setup a VPN with 2 linux box doing the encryption/decryption.

At the moment, I work on layer 3 with the linux framework **xfrm** (IP packets from host 1 are transformed into ESP when passing through the first box before being sent to host 2, decryption being done on the second box).

I'd like to act directly on layer 2 so I can remove the IP address of my boxes. I think I can do that by setting up ethernet bridges on each box, using netfilters hooks to redirect frames to a socket where a userspace program would do the encryption of the ethernet frames payload (transform the IP packets into ESP).

**|Host 1|**==|Ethernet Bridge|==Router --- (network not secure) --- Router==|Ethernet Bridge|==**|Host 2|**

Problem I have with this implementation lies in throughput as I think all these actions would greatly reduce it. Are there other ways I could implement what I'm looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Layer-2 only works from host-to-host (your router is just a host to layer-2) on a LAN. layer-2, including layer-2 encryption, does not cross a layer-3 device, e.g. router. MACsec (IEEE 802.1AE) is used for layer-2 encryption.

Layer-3 is used to connect LANs, and if you want end-to-end encryption from one LAN to another LAN, you need to encrypt on a layer higher than layer-2. Routers strip layer-2 frames from the packets, switch the packets, then create a new frame for the next hop. The next hop may not use MAC addresses; PPP is common for ISP connections, it doesn't use MAC addresses, and the frames are very different than ethernet. Unless you control all the links between the LANs, you need to encrypt at a high layer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What i'm looking for is only to encrypt the payload of the ethernet frame (an IP packet) so nothing would change on the packet flow, as the encrypted packets would still have a correct IP header (following ESP rfc4303)

basically I'd juste like to setup IPSec without having an IP address on the encryption/decryption devices

Answer (score 0):

You're right, deploying a layer 2 VPN is costly (in the sense that you have to pay for internet bandwidth) and most of the time useless, since there are few applications that won't work without being on the same LAN.

What you will get with a layer 2 VPN is mostly broadcasts, things like SMB out-of-the-box name resolution (does not apply if you have to connect to an AD server or have a WINS server), DLNA, SPX/IPX or LAN-only games will work seamlessly, on the other hand your perception on having to relay lots of possibly useless information will also be correct.

Maybe the solution you're looking for is to use [ebtables](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/) , which is a layer 2 firewall akin to iptables relating to layer 3 in such way that you can drop some packets while accepting others before relaying it over VPN/internet/etc.

PPP just one layer 2 protocol, there's nothing special about it, some VPN gateway use it (namely PPtP VPNs), others don't.